# multiple solr queries inside a for loop

Tags: node.js, express, solr

i am trying to run 2 solr queries in single for loop for fetching minimum and maximum value of a field from same solr core. The first query is running fine, but, second query is running each time for value in last index of array. My code is like this :

```
router.route('/might_be_interested').post(function (req, res) {
var merchant_id = req.body.merchant_id;
var data_merchants = []
var count1 = 0;
var count2 = 0;
var data = [];
var final_data = [];
var myStrQuery1 = 'q=merchant_id%3A' + merchant_id + '&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=category';
client_product.search(myStrQuery1, function (err, merchant_categories) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    var no_of_categories = merchant_categories.grouped.category.groups.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < no_of_categories; i++) {
        var category = merchant_categories.grouped.category.groups[i].groupValue;
        console.log(category);
        var myStrQuery2 = 'q=category%3A' + category + '&group=true&group.field=merchant_name&wt=json&indent=true';
        client_product.search(myStrQuery2, function (err, other_merchants) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            var no_of_merchants = other_merchants.grouped.merchant_name.groups.length;
            console.log(no_of_merchants);
            for (var j = 0; j < no_of_merchants; j++) {
                var merchants = other_merchants.grouped.merchant_name.groups[j].groupValue;
                if (data_merchants.indexOf(merchants) === -1) {
                    data_merchants.push(merchants)
                }
            }
            if (parseInt(count1) == (parseInt(no_of_categories) - 1)) {
                console.log(data_merchants)
                var distinct_merchant_count = data_merchants.length;
                console.log("distinct_merchant_count")
                console.log(distinct_merchant_count)
                for (var k = 0; k < distinct_merchant_count; k++) {
                    var distinct_merchant = data_merchants[k];
                    console.log(distinct_merchant)
                    var myStrQuery3 = 'q=merchant_name%3A('+distinct_merchant+')&sort=cashback_value+desc&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true';
                    client_product.search(myStrQuery3, function (err, max_cashback) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        var myStrQuery4 = 'q=merchant_name%3A('+distinct_merchant+')&sort=cashback_value+desc&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true';
                        client_product.search(myStrQuery4, function (err, min_cashback) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                return;
                            }
                            var maxcashback = max_cashback.response.docs[0].cashback_value;
                            var mincashback = min_cashback.response.docs[0].cashback_value;
                            var logolocation = max_cashback.response.docs[0].logo_location;
                            var merchantid = max_cashback.response.docs[0].merchant_id;
                            data.push(maxcashback)
                            data.push(mincashback)
                            data.push(logolocation)
                            data.push(merchantid)
                            final_data.push(data)
                            data = [];

                            if (parseInt(count2) == parseInt(distinct_merchant_count) - 1) {
                                send_response.sendSuccessData(final_data, res);
                            } else {
                                console.log("incerase counter");
                                count2 = parseInt(count2) + 1;
                            }


                        });


                    });
                }
                console.log("in end");
            } else {
                console.log("incerase counter");
                count1 = parseInt(count1) + 1;
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Thanks in advance. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You have the query inside the callback function for a query inside the callback function for a query inside a loop for the result from a query, so you'll have to drop the for-loop if you don't want to perform many searches for each search. There might be better ways to solve what you're trying to do if you express that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution using async.each. It is working properly in my case. this is the full code:

```
router.route('/might_be_interested').post(function (req, res) {
var merchant_name1 = req.body.merchant_name;
var count = 0;
var count3 = 0;
var data = [];
var data2 = [];
var merchants_info = []
var final_json_data = []
var myStrQuery1 = 'q=merchant_name%3A' + merchant_name1 + '&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=category';
client_product.search(myStrQuery1, function (err, merchant_categories) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    var length = merchant_categories.grouped.category.groups.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var category = merchant_categories.grouped.category.groups[i].groupValue;
        data2.push(category)
    }
    async.each(data2, function (category, callback) {
        var myStrQuery2 = 'q=category%3A' + category + '&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=merchant_name';
        client_product.search(myStrQuery2, function (err, other_merchants) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err1");
                return;
            }
            var no_of_merchants = other_merchants.grouped.merchant_name.groups.length;
            console.log("other_merchants")
            for (var j = 0; j < no_of_merchants; j++) {
                var merchants = other_merchants.grouped.merchant_name.groups[j].groupValue;
                var index = data.indexOf(merchants);
                if (index == -1) {
                    data.push(merchants);
                }
            }
            callback();
            console.log(data)
        });

    }, function (err) {
        // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
        if (err) {
            // One of the iterations produced an error.
            // All processing will now stop.
            console.log('A file failed to process');
        } else {
            async.each(data, function (merchant_name, callback) {
                console.log("merchant_name")
                console.log(merchant_name)
                var myStrQuery3 = 'q=merchant_name%3A('+merchant_name+')+AND+cashback_type%3A(percentage)%0A&sort=cashback_value+desc&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true';
                client_product.search(myStrQuery3, function (err, max_cashback) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("err2");
                        return;
                    }else{


                var myStrQuery4 = 'q=merchant_name%3A('+merchant_name+')+AND+cashback_type%3A(percentage)%0A&sort=cashback_value+desc&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true';
                    client_product.search(myStrQuery4, function (err, min_cashback) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("err3");
                            return;
                        }
                        merchants_info.push(merchant_name);
                        merchants_info.push(max_cashback.response);
                        merchants_info.push(min_cashback.response);
                        final_json_data.push(merchants_info)
                        merchants_info = [];
                        callback();
                    });
                    }
                });
            }, function (err) {
                // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
                if (err) {
                    // One of the iterations produced an error.
                    // All processing will now stop.
                    console.log('A file failed to process');
                } else {

                    console.log('in_loop');

                    send_response.sendSuccessData(final_json_data, res);

                    console.log("success");
                }
            });
            console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Solr 6 new Faceting implementation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search). You may just be able to group by Merchant and get your max and min, all in one Solr query.